# Django 2.2 i18n urlpatterns not being translated

Tags: django, django-i18n

I'm curious as if someone have tested using the i18n functionality of Django in the latest Django version?

I'm trying to internationalize my urlpatterns as following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('apps.frontpage.urls', namespace='frontpage')),
    path(_('journal/'), include('apps.journal.urls', namespace='journal')),
    path(_('projects/'), include('apps.projects.urls', namespace='projects')),
    path(_('software/'), include('apps.software.urls', namespace='software')),
    path('administration/', admin.site.urls),
)
```

using this `.po` file:

```
#: core/urls.py:22

msgid "journal/"
msgstr "dagbok/"

#: core/urls.py:23
msgid "projects/"
msgstr "prosjekter/"

#: core/urls.py:24
msgid "software/"
msgstr "programvare/"
```

The `.po` and `.mo` files are being generated and detected as the HTML menu gets translated like this:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'frontpage:index' %}"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> {% trans "Home" %}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'journal:index' %}"><i class="fas fa-book fa-fw"></i> {% trans "Journal" %}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'projects:index' %}"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram fa-fw"></i> {% trans "Projects" %}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'software:index' %}"><i class="fas fa-hdd fa-fw"></i> {% trans "Software" %}</a></li>
```

By this file:

```
#: shared/templates/sidebar.html:5
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Hjem"

#: shared/templates/sidebar.html:6
msgid "Journal"
msgstr "Dagbok"

#: shared/templates/sidebar.html:7
msgid "Projects"
msgstr "Prosjekter"

#: shared/templates/sidebar.html:8
msgid "Software"
msgstr "Programvare"

#: shared/templates/sidebar.html:10
msgid "Languages"
msgstr "Språk"
```

However, my urls are still not being translated. I'm not quite sure if I have done something wrong, or if this functionality is actually bugged in the latest Django version.

Do I need to configure anything else than

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shared/locale')
]
```

for it to detect `locale` directories within applications? or is this done automatically by Django?

Any help is appreciated. Entire source code is public on [GitHub](https://github.com/ggjersund/personal-website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by including my "core" application in the settings file in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Slight oversight from my part when reading the docs.

Source: [Documentation - How Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations), second bulletpoint.